# Merge multiple results to one Column

Tags: sql-server, database, select, aggregation

I would like to create a select statement to merge multiple results into one rot

I was able to realized what I want via PHP but i think it should be possible to work directly with Sql.

```
Notes
| ID | Name |
|----|------|
| 2  | Test |
| 3  | Test |

EditorAssignment
| UserID | NoteID |
|--------|--------|
| 1      | 2      |
| 2      | 2      |

UserList
| ID | username |
|----|----------|
| 1  | testuser |
| 2  | bUser    |
| 3  | cUser    |
```

I would like to have the following Result:

```
| NoteID | User            |
|--------|-----------------|
| 2      | testuser, bUser |
| 3      | cUser           |
```

How can i create a select like that in SQL2012?

Comment: Give us your code, what have you done so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before SQL Server 2017 (which has [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregate function for this), you need to use the famous `FOR XML PATH` correlated subquery:

SetUp:

```
DECLARE @Notes TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Notes (ID, Name) 
VALUES (2, 'Test'), (3, 'Test')

DECLARE @EditorAssignment TABLE (UserID INT, NoteID INT)

INSERT INTO @EditorAssignment (UserID, NoteID)
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2), 
    (3, 3) -- Added missing row here

DECLARE @UserList TABLE (ID INT, username VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @UserList (ID, username)
VALUES (1, 'testuser'), (2, 'bUser'), (3, 'cUser')
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    NoteID = N.ID,
    [User] = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT
                ', ' + U.username
            FROM
                @EditorAssignment AS E
                INNER JOIN @UserList AS U ON E.UserID = U.ID
            WHERE
                N.ID = E.NoteID     -- Link the outmost Notes' note with the inner EditorAssignment (correlated subquery)
            FOR XML
                PATH ('')           -- FOR XML PATH('') makes the SELECT return a string value, not a result set
        ),
        1, 
        2, 
        '')
FROM
    @Notes AS N
```

Results:

```
NoteID  User
2       testuser, bUser
3       cUser
```

The subquery generates a string with each username for the related assignment for each note.

The `STUFF` function is used just to replace the first `', '`, since the string is build with a leading comma and a space. This is why the parameters of the [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are 1 (first position of the string), 2 (amount of places to remove, the comma and the space), and `''` (replacement for those characters).

I'm guessing that you have a row missing for the `EditorAssignment` table that holds the values `3, 3` on your example.

Comment: right, but when i use stuff like this, it end up with a result like "2; testuser,testuser" & "2; bUser, bUser"

Comment: @MThiele please include the full example and the actual query you are using. I can't reproduce what you are saying, nor fix what I can't see.

Comment: im sorry, it was my fault. I made a mistake in the sub select. Thanks four your time!

Comment: @MThiele glad to help.